# Issue Fading in Content

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Having a bit of an issue fading in the content from my ajax page load.  The issue is, it does not fade in, it just shows instantly (after the delay).

Code:

```
    jQuery(window).on("load", function(){
    console.log('document ready');
    Initialize();
});
// Initialize all our scripts
function Initialize(){
    // Ajax page loading
    var $a = jQuery('[data-loadajax="true"]');
    var $body = jQuery('.main');
    $a.bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        var $href = $this.attr('href');
        $body.fadeOut('slow', function(){
            jQuery('#loading').fadeIn('fast');
            loadPage($href, $body); 
        });
    });
    // Load up the masonry stuff (now checks to see if the grid exists first)
    FireExtras();
}
function loadPage(strPageToLoad, strWhereToLoadIt) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: strPageToLoad,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        data: {'_t':Math.floor(+new Date() / 1000)},
        success: function (html) {
            // Get just the body
            // Get the full HTML of the return
            var $html = jQuery(html);
            $container = $html.find('.main');
            // Get Title
            var $title = $html.filter('title').text();
            // Get the Meta Description
            var $desc = $html.filter('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');
            // Get the Meta Keywords
            var $keyw = $html.filter('meta[name="keywords"]').attr('content');
            // Get the Meta Author          
            var $auth = $html.filter('meta[name="author"]').attr('content');
            // Get the scripts
            var $scripts = $html.filter('script');
            // Write out the Body
            jQuery(strWhereToLoadIt).html($container);
            // Hide the pre-loader, and show the body
            window.document.title = $title;
            jQuery('meta[name=description]').remove();
            jQuery('meta[name=keywords]').remove();
            jQuery('meta[name=author]').remove();
            jQuery('head').append('<meta name="description" content="' + $desc + '">');
            jQuery('head').append('<meta name="keywords" content="' + $keyw + '">');
            jQuery('head').append('<meta name="author" content="' + $auth + '">');
            window.history.replaceState(null, null, strPageToLoad);
            //window.location.replace(strPageToLoad);
            $scripts.remove();
            // Now let's fire up the scripts again, and pull in the appropriate script files...
            $scripts.each(function(i){
                //$.getScript(this.src);                
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('Loading...');
                jQuery(strWhereToLoadIt).fadeIn(3000, function(){
                    jQuery('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
                    FireExtras();
                });                 
            }, 10000);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('DANGER WILL ROBINSON!');
            window.location.href = strPageToLoad;
        }
    });
}
function FireExtras(){
    var menu = new cbpTooltipMenu( document.getElementById( 'cbp-tm-menu' ) );
    if(jQuery('#grid').length){
        new AnimOnScroll(document.getElementById('grid'), {
            minDuration: 0.4,
            maxDuration: 0.7,
            viewportFactor: 0.2
        });
    }
}
```

How can I get the `success` functionality to `fadeIn` the content instead of displaying it right away?

Even the .delay is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was writing the content in prior to fading it in, once I chained `jQuery(strWhereToLoadIt).html($container);` into

```
jQuery(strWhereToLoadIt).fadeIn(3000, function(){
                jQuery('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
                FireExtras();
            });
```

So it becomes:

```
jQuery(strWhereToLoadIt).html($container).fadeIn(3000, function(){
                jQuery('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
                FireExtras();
            });
```

It works

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PW9V2/) does what you want to happen.

HTML:

```
<button id="clickMe">click me</button>
<div id="showUp">visible or hidden?</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#showUp').hide().fadeIn(2000);
    //FireExtras();
});
```

CSS: none, styling is up to you ;)

**EDIT**

First of alle we should make sure, the page is completely loaded before we do something with JS/jQuery. Therefore we use

```
$('window').ready(function(){
    alert('document ready');
    Initialize();
});
```

See your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyNMA/1/).

Comment: updated code to reflect the entire method... as you can see in my click event, I am hiding it (via fadeOut)

Comment: You might want to create a jsFiddle of your own to explicate the problem. Makes it easier for us! Otherwise we keep on guessing what the problem might be.

Comment: seriously?  no, how about a link to the page(s) in question?  http://lmbrjack.o7th.com/

Comment: Seriously. Allows us to manipulate your code and give you improved answers. We can't do that on your page. Addendum: You don't have to provide all of your code, just a working fragment of the important part.

Comment: ok, you can't copy/paste the code into your own page and test it?   here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/gVsg3/

Comment: part of the issue was: `window.location.replace(strPageToLoad);`  apparently, even though I thought it was supposed to only update the history record, it was causing the page itself to change locations.  Once I removed it, the delay started working again. (even though I changed it to `setTimeout`    The `fadeIn` of the content still does not happen though, as you can see I updated it to take 3 seconds to complete the fadeIn, but it shows instantly

Comment: So far so good. I edited my answer for an updated version of your fiddle. So far so good - if youcould add the html structure of your document, we can test where the problem is :)

Answer (score -1):

You're animating the `opacity` style, which by default starts at 1. Make sure you set the opacity to 0 before you start animating.

```
jQuery(strWhereToLoadIt).css("opacity", 0).delay(1000).queue(function () {
    ...
```

**Edit:**
I'll take a stab at what I think is happening...
I believe when you use `fadeOut` jQuery animates the opacity style then removes it when finished and applies `display:none` to keep it hidden. That means its opacity value will revert back to the default `1` after fadeOut, so when you try to animate the opacity to 1, it makes no difference.

I would recommend using `jQuery(this).fadeIn('slow');` rather than animating the opacity.

Comment: updated code to reflect the entire method... as you can see in my click event, I am hiding it (via fadeOut)

Comment: as you probably can see from the code that I've posted, that I've tried that as well...